# How to get the values with highest number of records with same value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table say "deal".it has got a field 'category'. i would like to know the top 2 categories from this table, which are the categories having highest number of 'deals'.

for eg: there are 20 deals with category "cars" and 10 deals with category "bikes"  and 5 with category "cycles"

I want to get the result as cars,bikes (which has the highest number of deals.)

How can i query this using mysql without effecting performance?

Comment: `select ... order by count(categories) desc limit 2`. fill in the rest yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14008/13/0) that demonstrates the below query:

```
SELECT category
FROM deal
GROUP BY category 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 2
```